# locally asymptotically stable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

So, I am slightly confused about something that is written on Wikipedia regarding Lyapunov stability, namely: it says that if some function $V(x)$ is such that $\dot{V}(x) < 0$ $\forall \ x \in B$, where $B$ is some set excluding the origin, then the equilibrium point is *locally* asymptotically stable. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_function#Locally_asymptotically_stable_equilibrium)

Am I to understand this that if you can only show that $\dot{V(x)} < 0$ within some set containing the equilibrium point, then this point is locally stable, but not globally stable. For global stability, one needs to show that $B = \mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Thanks.
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. Looking down two headings on the wikipedia page, you have:

> If the Lyapunov-candidate-function $ V$ is globally positive definite, radially unbounded and the time derivative of the Lyapunov-candidate-function is globally negative definite: $\dot {V}(x)<0 ~\forall x\in \mathbb {R} ^{n}\setminus \{0\}$,
>   then the equilibrium is proven to be globally asymptotically stable.
>    The Lyapunov-candidate function $V(x)$ is radially unbounded if $\|x\|\to \infty \implies V(x)\to \infty $. (This is also referred to as norm-coercivity.)

Roughly speaking, the maximal set $\mathcal{B}$ (w.r.t. inclusion) on which you can show $\dot V (x) < 0$ would be the basin of attraction for the equilibrium. Note that this isn't quite precise due to some topological concerns (certainly everything within $\mathcal{B}$ approaches the equilibrium, but there could be other points in the basin of attraction for which there is no such $V$ and $\mathcal{B}$).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that.. I guess I'm still slightly confused because Boyce and diPrima say the following: "If V is positive-definite and $\dot{V}$ is negative-definite on *Some domain D* containing the origin, then the origin is an *asymptotically* stable critical point, which is a much stronger result than just being stable. But, here they just use a domain "D", not all of R^n.

Comment: Two Points:  "Stable" translates to "perturbations don't run away" while "asymptotically stable" translates to "perturbations decay" and we approach the equilibrium point. For example, a center is generally considered stable but not asymptotically stable.

Comment: Second point: $\dot V(x) <0$ tells us that "solutions flow downhill"--think of water running downhill and collecting in basins. If we show $\dot V (x) <0$ on a domain $D$, then solutions in $D$ must approach our equilibrium point, but there might be other solutions *outside* of $D$ that go elsewhere (drop of water fell on the other side of a ridge and flows towards a different lake). If we can show that $\dot V(x) <0$ on $D=\mathbb{R}^n$ (as well as other listed hypotheses), then every initial condition "runs downhill" to our globally stable equilibrium point.

Comment: Ahh. I see. So, if you can show for a center for example that $\dot{V} < 0$ on a domain $D$, then would that center be asymptotically stable by this theorem in Boyce and di Prima?

Comment: Right, except that you've shown that it actually *can't* be a center and must actually be a spiral sink (upon consideration for higher order terms if you were looking at the linearization). A center is Lyapunov stable, but not asymptotically stable.

Comment: Okay. So, your answers are very helpful. I've been confused about the centre equilibrium point all afternoon, so I've been searching online, and I found this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.01310.pdf Here, the author claims that the point P3 is a centre (because of purely imaginary eigenvalues), but then uses this Boyce and di Prima theorem to show that it is asymptotically stable. (That is what led me to search this text). Further, this page : http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Equilibrium describes a centre with purely imaginary eigenvalues. So, does this paper have an error?

Comment: While Lyapunov stable, centers are somewhat degenerate. A small perturbation to the system can lead to a phase transition to either being a spiral source or a spiral sink (something that linearization might not be able to detect). Refining the classification of a center is one of the hallmark applications for a Lyapunov function. See the paragraph after equation (40). In this case, the authors only care about local stability, as the existence of other equilibria rules out global stability (there's already at least one initial condition that doesn't approach P3).

Comment: Wow! You read that fast. So, the centres in this paper are asymptotically stable, but, not globally stable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55873/discussion-between-erfink-and-thomas-moore).